# Evaluate a variable or expression inside a string in Sass

Tags: css, sass

I want to create a mixin for setting a div to transparent. The -ms-filter line needs to be quoted, but it also needs to contain the result of a calculation ($amount * 100).  How do I evaluate a variable in a string?

```
@mixin transparent( $amount: .7, $color: black ) {
    background: $color;
    -ms-filter: progid:"DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=$amount * 100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity= $amount * 100);
    opacity: $amount;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use interpolation to force the evaluation of the variable or expression to happen, otherwise Sass will treat it like any other string content:

```
@mixin transparent( $amount: .7, $color: black ) {
    background: $color;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=#{$amount * 100})";
    filter: alpha(opacity= $amount * 100);
    opacity: $amount;
}
```

Comment: I guess I should have guessed that would work. Thanks! for the next person, here's the documentation: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_